# Why is the first item of a ComboBox is selected after switch to another TabItem?

Tags: wpf, combobox, selection, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` with three `TabItems`. In each of the `TabItems` is one `ComboBox`. If I switch through the `TabItems` the first entry of the `ComboBoxes` is selected. But I want that nothing is selected. How to do it?

Here are some screenshots:

After the first call of the form, there is nothing selected
[image]

After the switch to the second tab, the first element of the combobox is selected
[image]

Update: This is the code for this example

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="525" SizeToContent="Height">
<Grid>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Test 1">
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test 2">
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Test 3">
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

No binding. A brand new project in Visual Studio Express 2010.

And here is the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
      public MainWindow()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are they both bound to the same `ItemSource`?

Comment: No, this are all simple comboboxes without any binding.

Comment: Why are you setting the selection if you don't want it selected?, Just remove the `SelectedIndex` values

Comment: I added `SelectedIndex` only to show an item. If I remove `SelectedIndex` nothing changes. The first item is still selected.

Comment: I can't replicate that, If I remove `SelectedIndex` nothing gets selected.

Comment: I just created a new wpf project in visual studio and pasted the code from above without `SelectedIndex` and nothing changes. The combobox is still selected (blue balckground) after switch to another tab.

Comment: Same here... I can't reproduce it... Are you sure you're not Binding somewhere, or setting the SelectedIndex? Does the SelectedIndex change EVERY time you switch tabs, or is it just defaulted when you first startup?

Comment: @Smolla I've just copied the code and created a new project, there is no default selection! (blue backround appears as default focus behavior)

Comment: Unfortunately, I too cannot recreate the problem. Why not open up a new project and post the code you have provided. Let us know if you are still getting that problem.  Or, in Visual Studio, please press `F5` so we can see the code behind.  Copy that code and post it.

Comment: `F7` views code-behind with the default Visual Studio shortcuts

Comment: @makc your advice gave me a new direction. If I set 'focusable' to false, the blue background disappears. But now I can't use the tab key to jump to the combobox.

Comment: Thank to @makc I know that the first focusable child in tabitem gets focused. _How could I avoid this behavior?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your help and a long journey through the web, I now know, that there is no way to avoid the behavior, that the first focusable child on tabitem gets focused, without some code behind :(

Thank you all for your answers, especially @makc for his advice, that the blue background means, that the combobox is focused.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no error in the example code.

Is this code?

Try to remove any item is selected or if there is binding say it to give you an answer.

[image: No error]

Comment: There is nothing selected and there is no binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `FocusVisualStyle` to `null` for combobox -

```
            <ComboBox FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Although i was not able to recreate the problem with the code you posted above.

Comment: Nothing changed. The combobox is the first focusable child in the TabItem and it got focused, which means the background changes to blue.